# How can I model such a distribution consisting of a mix of different distribution types?

Tags: distributions, modeling, mixture-distribution, hyperparameter

Excuse the title, suggestions are welcome but I wasn't able to come up with an easier one.

---

I am trying to find a simple model which "kind of", at least visually, appears to follow a distribution like $\frac{1}{N}\mathcal{N}(\mu_{1i}, \sigma_{1i}) + \mathcal{N}(\mu_{2i}, \sigma_{2i})$ where $\mu_{1i} = 0, \forall i$ and $N$ is the normalization constant. $\mu_{1k}$ means "*$\mu$ of component $1$ in state $k$*" and so on.

The very important idea behind that is, that now I only have to predict three (excluding $\mu_{1i}$) parameters in each state in order to receive a useful approximation.

It's probably easier to show this in terms of a plot. Below I am fitting a gaussian mixture model with one component the first time, and two components the second time. The code should be copy & pasteable.

```py
# %matplotlib inline # In case you're using Jupyter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab    
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

ls = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)

offsets = [0, 15, 45, 60]

for nb_components in [1, 2]:

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(offsets), 1, figsize=(16, 6), 
                             sharey=True, sharex=True)

    for i, offset in enumerate(offsets):

        # Create a distribution consisting of to gaussians ..
        distribution = mlab.normpdf(ls, 0, 3) + mlab.normpdf(ls, offset, 7) 
        distribution = distribution / distribution.sum()

        # Draw samples from that disitributions (this is the "real world" data)
        random_samples = np.random.choice(range(100), 10000, p=distribution)
        random_samples = np.asmatrix(random_samples).T

        # Now fit a gaussian mixture model on those samples
        gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=nb_components)
        r = gm.fit(random_samples)

        # Add up all the gaussians and normalize it
        d = [np.sum([mlab.normpdf(ls, mu[0], np.sqrt(covariance[0]))
             for mu, covariance in zip(r.means_, r.covariances_)], axis=0)]
        d = d / np.sum(d)

        # Plotting the results
        ax = axes[i]
        ax.plot(ls, distribution, label='Original', 
                color='r', linestyle='--', alpha=.5)
        ax.plot(ls, d.T, label='Fitted')
        ax.set_ylabel('State {:d}'.format(i+1))

    axes[0].set_title('Components: {:d}'.format(nb_components))
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
```

The resulting plots look like this:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the first model, which uses only one component, is rather poor. The second one though, using two components, looks "almost" promising.

However, as you can see the biggest error occurs at the border. It is obvious that I might want to replace the first component $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_{1i})$ with something else.

The two issues I am currently facing is:

1. What should I chose for the first component and
2. How can I fit the new model in order to receive receive the hyper parameters I want to predict further?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In theory, mixture components can rely on any probability distribution.
The border looks similar to a sigmoid function, here is a plot https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/lhk/d56484a62bf3da92b8e9032bab8fa195

Please note that I flipped the sigmoid function, usually it models a step-up, not the step-down in your data.

In order to convert this to a distribution, you should normalize it:
[image]

This function, combined with Gaussian models for the other parts of your data, should be able to fit the curve.

The second part of your question, how to implement this, is going to be more complicated. I've browsed the scipy docs, but it seems like they only have builtin support for gaussian mixtures. I don't think that you can add your own distributions.

This probably means that you'll have to reimplement the expectation maximization algorithm.

Maybe someone else can come up with a prepackaged solution.

Comment: Hm, I have found [this](https://github.com/sseemayer/mixem) which is unfortunately a bit abandoned.